# Pyrolysis of calcium chloride dihydrate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, pyrolysis

Does the pyrolysis of $\ce{CaCl2 · 2 H2O}$ give $\ce{CaCl2 + 2 H2O}$ or $\ce{Ca(OH)2 + 2 HCl}?$

Comment: What temperatures are we talking about?

Comment: Ordinary heating

Comment: I did synthesis of uranium tungstates for quite some time and was imprinted to me that "*ordinary heating*" is supposed to be 900–1100 °C. An organic chemist would probably understand "*ordinary heating*" as some elevated temperature around the boiling point of water. So, again, *what temperatures are we talking about*?

Comment: About the boiling point of H2O

Comment: AFAIK nothing will happen. Dihydrate only starts to decompose (aka give away water of crystallization) at 175 °C.

Comment: @andselisk Actually, I think I would consider *ordinary heating* reflux for whatever the solvent is. Which can go down to room temperature for ether or DCM ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All calcium chloride hydrates give away water of crystallization upon heating without forming a hydroxide, and the anhydrous $\ce{CaCl2}$ melts without decomposition [1, p. 162]:

> anhydrous salts melts at 772 °C, while the mono-, di-, tetra- and hexahydrates decompose at 260 °C, 175 °C, 45.5 °C and 30 °C, respectively; the anhydrous salt vaporizes at 1935 °C.

$$\ce{CaCl2 · x H2O ->[\pu{260 °C}] CaCl2 + x H2O}$$

Calcium chloride dihydrate would remain intact until its melting/decomposition point at 175 °C.
When heated quickly in the absence of desiccant, [the powdered salt is dissolved in its own water of crystallization forming glass-alike solid upon cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_chloride#Laboratory_and_related_drying_operations).

#### References

1. Patnaik, P. *Handbook of Inorganic Chemicals*; McGraw-Hill handbooks; McGraw-Hill: New York, **2003**. ISBN 978-0-07-049439-8.